# PHP insert into database query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert values into a database table, a row is inserted but blank no values are inserted. Only the order_id which is the primary key with auto increment increase.

php code:

```
<?php
        $user_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users"); 
        while($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_get)){
            if($row_user['username'] == $_SESSION['username']){
                $row_user['first_name'] = $res1;
                $row_user['last_name'] = $res2;

                $store_order ="INSERT INTO oko (user, product) VALUES ('$res1', '$res2')";
                mysql_query($store_order);
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure $res1 and $res2 have a value? Print $store_order before you execute the query;

Comment: LOL seems you'll be having a hard time to pick the right answer from the three answers provided :D

Comment: :D i know crazy choice :D

Comment: like my question as well ppl :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assignments are backwards. I think you meant to:

```
$res1 = $row_user['first_name'];
$res2 = $row_user['last_name'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't you mean:

```
$res1 = $row_user['first_name'];
$res2 = $row_user['last_name'];
```

You could also update the `SELECT` to have a WHERE clause that checks `$_SESSION['username']`.

You could *also* just do an INSERT/SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO oko (user, product)
SELECT
    first_name, last_name
FROM
    users
WHERE
    username = '$_SESSION["username"]'
```

---

Your code is vulnerable to injection.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO/mysqli